# Paypal express checkout for nodejs application

Tags: php, node.js, angularjs, curl, paypal

I have a simple web app using nodejs which has some products. I have setup my  own cart using angularjs, and I want the simplest way to implement paypal payment. I have been breaking my head for the past two weeks over the long documentation of paypal.

I saw a sample curl call in developer page and implemented it using restler package in nodejs. and it returned the same token as of the curl  call (so i guess it works). I want to know how to make my app work with it.

```
var restler = require('restler');
restler.get('https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=PLEASEDONTPUTYOURUSERNAMEHERE&PWD=PLEASEDONTPUTENCRYPTEDPASSWORDSHERE&SIGNATURE=PLEASEDONTPUTYOURINFORMATIONHEREf&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=78&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html&returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html')
.on('complete',function(data){console.log(data);})
```

Really appreciate help with this. I am also open to any other way, but since I am not into long docs, its difficult for me to understand. Any simpler api calls to get this done? I just want to make my customers pay and then get the money to the bank. NO refunds or any other processes for now.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are simply requiring a way to receive payments using PayPal.

I don't get much to play with payment gateways, but when I do, I prefer to use an external library to help me though the way, as like with you, I prefer shorter documentation. Most of my work is with Ruby but some time back I was playing with Express to make a simple eCommerce application which eventually was done in Padrino.

Following are nearly a copy paste of my old notes, hopefully the information is not outdated and is functional.

**1: The library:**

You need to get the `paynode` library. It supports PayPal and some other payment gateways. I believe this information has to be in `package.json`

```
{ "name" : "my-shopping-cart"
  // Other information
 ,"dependencies":
    { 
      "paynode": "0.3.6",
      // other libraries
    }
}
```

followed by `npm install` I guess

**2: The configuration**

```
var payflow = require('paynode').use('payflow') 
var client  = payflow.createClient({ 
  level:payflow.levels.sandbox , 
  user:'username@example.com' , 
  password:'1279778545' , 
  signature: 'AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacA0hAtGdCbvZOkLhMJ8t2a.QoecEJ' 
})
```

3: **Get the info:**

Obtain the information to the server, probably though HTTP post ( I am not sure how it will be done as I am still starting to learn client side MV* frameworks ).

```
products = null;
total = 0;

/* Update values */

// products = getAllProducts()
// total = getTotal()

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:  'http://my-web-site.com/pay',
  data: { products: products, total:total },
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

**4: Some routes ( pay, confirm most important )**

```
app.post('/pay', function(req, res){
  // Store information
  // Calculate sums or any similar information 

  request.returnurl = 'http://my-web-site.com/confirm'
  request.cancelurl = 'http://my-web-site.com/cancel'

  // make request and handle response
  client.setExpressCheckout(request).on('success', function(response){
    tokenStore.store(req.sessionHash, response.token)
    res.redirect('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='+response.token)
  }).on('failure', function(response){
    res.render('start.haml', {locals:{
      error:response.errors[0].longmessage
      }
    })
  })
})


app.get('/confirm', function(req, res){
  // Necessary fetching - ex: user
  client.getExpressCheckoutDetails({token:req.param('token')})
    .on('success', function(response){
      // Save the order
      // orders.save(req.sessionHash, response)
      res.render('confirm.haml', {
        locals:{
          paypalResponse:response,
          orderTotal:response.paymentrequest[0].amt
        }
      })     
    })
    .on('failure', function(response){
      res.render('error.haml', {locals:{error:response.errors[0].longmessage}})
    })
})
```

Most if not all code above would have come from this URL: https://github.com/jamescarr/node-shopping-cart

Useful link on eBay developer page: http://go.developer.ebay.com/devzone/articles/integrating-paypal-express-checkout-your-nodejs-app